# jquery finding the element one element over

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, element

Ok. I have my html setup like.

```
<div id="wrap">
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="right">
      <a href="#">link</a>
   </div>
   <div class="listings" style="display:none">
      <ul>
         <li>Listing 1</li>
         <li>Listing 2</li>
         <li>Listing 3</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is when the link in "right" is clicked it will find the listings div and then show it, problem is, I need to know the height of the UL container prior to showing it so I can resize and show accordingly.

The other issue is, the content is dynamicly created so it can have multiple left/right/listings combinations displayed on the page. I don't handle that portion of the product I just develop the front end UI to work with the stuff put out. So I'm at an impass as I have tried everything I can think of from siblings to parents to find maybe I am just tackling it wrong..

Here is an example of the same as above but what it can look like with more than one instance (which is part of my issue I think)..

```
<div id="wrap">
       <div class="left"></div>
       <div class="right">
          <a href="#">link</a>
       </div>
       <div class="listings" style="display:none">
          <ul>
             <li>Listing 1</li>
             <li>Listing 2</li>
             <li>Listing 3</li>
          </ul>
       <div>
       <div class="left"></div>
       <div class="right">
          <a href="#">link</a>
       </div>
       <div class="listings" style="display:none">
          <ul>
             <li>Listing 1</li>
             <li>Listing 2</li>
             <li>Listing 3</li>
          </ul>
       <div>
       <div class="left"></div>
       <div class="right">
          <a href="#">link</a>
       </div>
       <div class="listings" style="display:none">
          <ul>
             <li>Listing 1</li>
             <li>Listing 2</li>
             <li>Listing 3</li>
          </ul>
       <div>
       <div class="left"></div>
       <div class="right">
          <a href="#">link</a>
       </div>
       <div class="listings" style="display:none">
          <ul>
             <li>Listing 1</li>
             <li>Listing 2</li>
             <li>Listing 3</li>
          </ul>
       <div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?:

```
$(".right a").click(function( e ) {
    $(this) //a-element
        .parent() // div.right
            .next() // div.listings
            .toggle(); //Hide and show depending on what it was
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You can remove the comments and write it on one line if you want.

if its dynamic loaded with AJAX or not loaded on the DOM you can use live event:

```
$(".right a").click("click", function( e ) {
    $(this) //a-element
        .parent() // div.right
            .next() // div.listings
            .toggle(); //Hide and show depending on what it was
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: use the `live()` method of jquery to bind an event to all current and future dom elements matching your selector

Comment: only question to that though is how do I find the UL within it so I can get it's height()?

Comment: After `.toogle()` you can add `.find("ul").height()` and save it on a variable

Answer (score 1):

You just need to go up one level (`parent`), move to the next element (`next`), and show it:

```
$('.right a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().show();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/jRVxe/

I'm assuming that you're HTML was a little messed up, I think a lot of the `<div>` should have been `</div>`:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right">
        <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listings" style="display:none">
        <ul>
            <li>Listing 1</li>
            <li>Listing 2</li>
            <li>Listing 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right">
        <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listings" style="display:none">
        <ul>
            <li>Listing 1</li>
            <li>Listing 2</li>
            <li>Listing 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right">
        <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listings" style="display:none">
        <ul>
            <li>Listing 1</li>
            <li>Listing 2</li>
            <li>Listing 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right">
        <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listings" style="display:none">
        <ul>
            <li>Listing 1</li>
            <li>Listing 2</li>
            <li>Listing 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must keep some mapping for it for say keep an ID for listing divs and and invoke a function on click of link that contains the id.

> ```
> >  <div class="left"></div>
> >        <div class="right">
> >           <a href="#" onclick="someFunction('id1');">link</a>
> >        </div>
> >        <div id="id1" class="listings" style="display:none">
> >           <ul>
> >              <li>Listing 1</li>
> >              <li>Listing 2</li>
> >              <li>Listing 3</li>
> >           </ul>
> >        <div>
> ```

else it will be very confusing for you

Comment: You dont need an ID, you can use the DOM structure to find related `.listings` for all the `.right a`

Comment: in case you dont add ID's it will be very confusing to maintain it... what in case an extra div needs to be added in near future... will require script changes...

Comment: I disagree, how do you reference the ID on an a-element to what ID to show, because you really don´t want to use in-line events on an element, and using the HTML5 `data-` attribute could solve it but if you are redoing the HTML markup you should redo the Javascript also anyway. But this is my personal opinion. I would´t redo the HTML markup.

Comment: hmmm agree!!! with your point.. but it was just like saving some time to some stuff